# VS Code: how to change color of XML attributes

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, token, color-scheme

How to change the color of the *XML attributes*, in Visual Studio Code ?

For example, how to choose another color for the `identifiant` attributes below:
[image: xml sample]

Here are the current color theme settings:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Solarized Dark]": {
        "keywords": "#f00"
    },
    "functions": "#f5896e",
    "numbers": "#dfd51b",
    "keywords": "#215c21",
    "strings": "#67f7e3",
    "variables": "#22FF88",
    "comments": "#332244"
}
```

or more visually

[image: Color theme]

**In other words: is there any token that applies specifically to *"XML attributes"* ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, using the `Scopes` inspector - invoke the command `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`

you will see that xml attributes names have the scope `entity.other.attribute-name.localname.xml`.  So you can add this textmate rule to your `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting:

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {

        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name.localname.xml",
            "settings": {
              "foreground": "#f3873f",
              "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
          },
        ]
  }
```

See [textmate scopes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#textmate-tokens-and-scopes) for more.